# Как получить имя по Id?

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть таблица заказов, которая хранит в себе заказчиков через внешние ключи

Id передается, всё остальное - нет, следовательно что-то получить из таблица заказчиков у меня не получается

Как можно получить объект или что-то вроде того?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заказчики:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Contragent { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Delivery { get; set; }
    public bool IsCashless { get; set; }
}
```

Заказы:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    //Не всё, самое простое и не относящееся отрезал
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int? MaterialId { get; set; }
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    public int? DeliveryAddressId { get; set; }
    public DeliveryAddress DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код класса заказа (Order). Часть свойств можно опустить для краткости.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, прикрепил

Comment: Я удалил нерелевантные метки, т. к. вопрос не относится к веб-программированию и ASP.NET.

Comment: Ваш вопрос по Entity Framework. Укажите что именно используете: EF 6 или EF Core?

Comment: EF6 - [Loading Related Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data), EF Core - [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете ORM Entity Framework, то при извлечении данных Order из DbSet следует добавить метод Include() с указанием данных, которые вы хотите включить:

`this.db.Orders.Include(order => order.Customer);`

Если в последствии появится внешний ключ у Customer, то следует дополнить запрос методом .ThenInclude():

`this.db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).ThenInclude(customer => customer.FK);`

Comment: Но у меня уже есть внешний ключ на Customers как:
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

Comment: Всё верно CustomerId это ключ, который хранится в табилце, объект public Customer Customer { get; set; } лишь даёт возможность обращаться к данным внутри кода. Информация по этому объекту хранится в другой таблице и её нужно извлечь отдельно, для этого и используется Include.